# Self-adjoint operator and inner product

Tags: linear-algebra, analysis, functional-analysis, operator-theory, inner-products

I am wondering whether there is a way to make sense of self adjointness of an operator on $C[0,1]$ without resorting to the inner product of $L^2[0,1]$.

I am not referring to concrete alternative ways to check, but rather to whether it is even sensible to ask whether an operator is self-adjoint if one does not have an inner product.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The adjoint of an operator $T: X \to X$ is $T^*:  X^* \to X^*$ given by 
$(T^* f)(x) = f(T x)$.  Now in the case of $X = C[0,1]$ you have an embedding
$J$ of $X$ in $X^*$ given by $(Jx)(y) = \int_0^1 x(t) y(t)\ dt$, so you can 
ask for $T^* \circ J = J \circ T$.  Of course you could say this is introducing 
an inner product.  Moreover, there are many other possible embeddings $J$, each 
of which would give a different notion of "self-adjointness".